# Difference between Process managers (pm2), Job Queues (bull) and Message Brokers (RabbitMQ)

Tags: node.js, architecture, rabbitmq, pm2, worker

I'd like to receive clarification about differences between process managers (pm2), job queue managers (bull, agenda), and message brokers (RabbitMQ) and their use cases.

> *Before we start:*
>
> - *I am not asking about, what's better, but I am asking, in which cases some of these modules can be used appropriately and in which I should not use them at all*
> - *My own thoughts and sub-questions, that I'd want to be answered are **marked with bold** after each use-case. I understand that the whole question is complex, so I have nothing to add. Feel free to write it down. You'll receive my reaction and upvote in case if your answer is useful.*

As I understand it:

- the message broker is responsible only for delivering messages between various microservices (which could be written in different frameworks and languages), but it's doesn't have any impact on processes/tasks.
- process and queue managers are responsible for processes themselves, and if the job has logic like: `process.on("message" => ...)` process is capable to react for any input commands. (But if they are also capable to communicate with each other via [`node.js` worker_threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) we don't need RabbitMQ at all.)

For example, imagine my use-cases are the following:

#### Queue 10 workers, with each 2 in parallel.

I have one `worker.js` file with a long and heavy resourceful task. And I want to run 10 instances of it, but in parallel of 2 times at once.

```
=1=>
=2=>
    =3=>
    =4=>
        =..n1=>
        =..n2=>
```

In that case, as I understand it, [`pm2`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2) won't help me, but job queue managers like [`bull`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bull) will. **Am I right here?**

#### Selectively send a command to workers/jobs

But let's imagine, for now, I want to run all the `worker.js` tasks in parallel. -Great, now they are running but waiting for my input command. Doesn't matter how exactly, via `http/ws/cli/etc`.

And what if I want to select only processes with certain PIDs (or select them by my own certain criteria) and send commands only for them, except other `worker.js` instances.

Like this:

```
User: 
run all threads         PID1, PID3 print "hello"

Threads:
 ==1=wait_for_input======="hello"=======>
 ==2=wait_for_input=====================>
 ==3=wait_for_input======="hello"=======>
```

**Does in that case I need any message broker?** Or such job managers like `bull` or `agenda` and their UI (like [`bull-board`](https://github.com/vcapretz/bull-board)) will allow me to selectively send commands only for necessary jobs in the queue?"

> *In that case, our `worker.js` instances will be capable to react to incoming "messages" via `process.on` trigger.*

#### Role of process managers (like pm2 and nodemon)

And if queue managers are capable to run tasks separate / in-parallel, **why do we need such things as `pm2` at all?** Are process managers replaceable by job managers? Or we need such thing as `pm2`, only to start `bull` which will maintain queries?

Comment: Nodemon is not a process manager that you use on production rather a development server for node.js application which watches for file changes and restarts the node.exe. Mostly you use PM2 as a process manager on production server if you are running your node.js on multiple cores/clustering to load balance the requests to multiple node.exe processes and it has other useful features such as monitoring/logging. PM2 also restarts the node.exe if it crashes due to an unhandled exceptions.

Comment: @KarthikSamyak, thank you so much for your comment. I know that about PM2, cause I am actually using it in production, which supervises 16 different processes for me. Guess I started to understand it now, that `pm2` for example can run not all 16, but only 2  (main) processes at the same time, and the rest of this process, could be easily run as `workers` for these two main processes and been managed by `bull` or `agenda`.